# Trouble connecting to Pi through SSH

Tags: wireless, ssh

Been stuck on the same problem for weeks now. I am trying to set up my Pi to run headless through SSH. It's connected to the LAN through a wireless USB stick. I connect using PuTTY and juice SSH on my tablet.

The problem is that sometimes I can connect and sometimes I can't. I have checked the IP address every time which is 192.168.0.22 port 22 and never changes. PuTTY has 192.168.0.22 port 22 set and autologin username "Pi" set under the data tab. Last night for example I couldn't connect for a about 30 minutes and then suddenly I could connect after enough attempts. No parameters had changed that I know of.

I have reformatted the SD card and reinstalled the OS 3 times. I have tried a new SD card. The Pi shows up on the router constantly so it's not an issue of the wireless dropping out.

I have also tried tight VNC and that is just as temperamental as SSH, although I need to use the Pi through HDMI and keyboard/mouse in order to start VNC server as I haven't configured it to run on boot.

I can't think of any other solutions or potential problems and can't find any related issues on any forums. Patients is starting to wear thin so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If it helps I have just disabled all firewall protection on tablet and laptop and still not able to connect on either.

Comment: 1. Take a look at /var/log/messages on the Pi, mainly during the time when you couldn't connect, if there are relevant entries, please post them here. 2. You can also use raspberrypi.local as the hostname, which will be resolved to the current IP your Pi uses.

Comment: if your using DHCP your IP may have expired, check your Client Lease Time in your router settings.

Comment: @user10543 Dumb question, but you said you set the username to **P**i (emphasis on the capital P there). Did you set it with the P capitalized, or did you set it to `pi` (all lowercase)? If you set it to Pi (capitalized) trying making it all lowercase.